# System not checking for updates in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: updates, 13.04

I have a system where I have the development version 13.04 that is not checking for updates.

From the command line "sudo apt-get update" completes without any error, and "sudo-apt-get upgrade" afterwards installs all the available updates without error. In system parameters "check updates daily" is marked, but the system refuses to do it, if I don't issue the "update" command manually no updates are offered.

I'm behind a proxy that is working perfectly otherwise. I have checked /etc/environment and /etc/apt/apt.conf and I can see the proxy correctly defined in these two places, and in any case as I said "sudo apt-get update" finds the repositories that I use without any error.

What can be preventing my system to check updates automatically?

Comment: Just to make it sure, did you double check your settings for the next two entries, namely "When there are ..."?

Comment: Yes, thanks, they are both marked "Display immediately"

Comment: My home machine runs 12.04, my office machine runs 13.04. Both have identical settings like you. I have not yet noticed whether my 13.04 machine is going for automatic updates. Every morning I put an `update` command. I will let you know once I see an automatic update happening in my office (13.04) machine. For the moment, looks like you can carry on manual updating and see what happens once the final version is released around the end of this month. Also, you may want to make a post in this forum, http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=427 (or keep on waiting till April 25).

Comment: As a matter of fact I have my laptop also with 13.04 and it is checking for updates without any issue, so it is something related to the system. I was asking just in any case anybody would know where to check or diagnose when the system is not checking. May be there is some daemon or something that should be running and it is not.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer to my own question in this old bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-notifier/+bug/390319

The problem is that the file /etc/cron.daily/apt is not executable.

To solve it, I opened a terminal and entered the following commands:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/cron.daily/apt
sudo rm /var/spool/anacron/cron.daily
```

(the first command makes the file executable, the second one removes the cron job and it is recreated after reboot)

After rebooting the system I got update notifications again.